# How to add add an image in a table using MySqlWorkbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to fill a table called `book`, in particular I need to insert an image in the field `image` of that table. This is the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ods`.`books` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `site` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` BLOB NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

this is the window of the software:

[image]

How can I add an image using the `inserts` windows of `MySqlWorkbench`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the blob field -> Load Value From File

[image]